# How to make sense of postgres explain analyze?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance, sql-execution-plan

The table data I have is around 2 million rows and the query that I am running as of now is just select all the data from the table (select *).

This is a pretty naive case of query optimisation, but the real intention that I want to understand is the explain analyze.

Here is the output from explain analyze with timing on.

**QUERY PLAN**

```
 Seq Scan on sample  (cost=0.00..37929.83 rows=2185783 width=26) (actual time=0.065..348.752 rows=2185712 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.102 ms
 Execution time: 463.020 ms
(3 rows)
```

So, the time for execution at the max is 0.3 seconds.

**Questions**

- How realistic is this time estimate ? I am running on Pgadmin to do select * on the rows and it takes 30 seconds.This makes sense since it needs to print out the entire data on the screen.But does this mean that the optimisation part on the db side is done and the problem we generally face is in printing the data
- I am printing the data by using JDBC.It takes around 45 seconds to fetch and print the data.Assuming that 0.3 seconds is the actual database time and the rest of the time is taken by the Java program to print it out? I am running on the same system, so Network I/O is ruled out.

I am a newbie to database optimisations, I am just trying to understand how to make sense of explain analyze in postgres and how to realistically estimate a query running time and how to find out whether any improvements on the database side is required?

Comment: The "actual time" is **not** an estimate. It is a measurement for time needed to execute the *actual* query (but ignoring / throwing away the results). The DMBS cannot estimate how long it will take to ship the results back to the client, so it does not even attempt to include this time in the calculations.

Comment: You're retrieving 2,185,712 rows, right?

Comment: @DavidAldridge : Yes, that's right (2 million).

Comment: @joop : On those lines, if the explain analyze tells me the actual time needed to execute the query, and if it is satisfactory, then there is nothing to be done on the database level to improve performance right?

Comment: Exactly. BTW: `I am running on the same system, so Network I/O is ruled out.`. No. a loopback device (and even a unix-domain socket) costs I/O, too (and a lot of context switches) And since you also us ODBC, the traffic needs to pass the interface *twice*, that amounts to *four* context switches per packet. Then add the ODBC cost and the core-surfing needs of the JAVA VM plus maybe the associated display.

Comment: Now if this was Oracle, I'd say to go look at event tracing, which would break down the entire 40 seconds or so of execution time into an excruciating level of detail, but most importantly how much of that time was spent by the server either sending data to the client, or waiting for the client to ask for more data. I don't think that PostgreSQL has that level of instrumentation though.

Comment: @joop : Thanks for that info. David : There should be something similar for postgres.Let me do some research and post answers here if I find any.

Answer (score 0):

The actual time shown by EXPLAIN ANALYZE is realistic. You can trust it as you want to optimize the database execution and not the other factors like - pulling it in Java, making objects from it, printing it, IOPS, etc. Time would also vary depending on other processes running at that time on your machine.

Comparing original plan and optimized plan always give you more realistic insights.

Most of the time query execution time is the problem. Other factors are pretty standard.

**How to decide if query optimisation is required or not:**
If you have some of these things in your query plan, then there are high chances that your query needs optimisation:

1. High number of loops.
2. If you have heap scans.
3. If number of rows filtered is very high.
4. Sequential scans on large tables.
5. You have indexes, but planner is not using them.
6. Majority of query execution is not thru index-only or index scans.

I use both of these tools to visualize my plans:

1. http://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans/new
2. https://explain.depesz.com